# Actualizar todos los registros de una tabla cuando inserto un nuevo registro

Tags: python, django

Tengo un modelo el cual tiene varias property, lo utilizo para registrar las lecturas de contadores de electricidad:

```
class ConsumoElect(models.Model):
    pgd = models.ForeignKey(TipoPGD, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='consumoelect')
    fecha = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    fecha_AM = models.CharField(max_length=20)  
    lec_madrugada = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    lec_dia = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    lec_pico = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    reactivo = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    dato = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    total = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.pgd)

    def get_cm(self):
        c_m = list(ConsumoElect.objects.filter(pgd=self.pgd).filter(fecha__gt=self.fecha).order_by('fecha').values('lec_madrugada')[0:1])    
        if not c_m:
            return 0
        else:
            if not c_m[0]['lec_madrugada']:
                return 0
            else: 
                return ((c_m[0]['lec_madrugada'] - self.lec_madrugada))    
    consumo_m= property(get_cm)

    def get_cd(self):
        c_d = list(ConsumoElect.objects.filter(pgd=self.pgd).filter(fecha__gt=self.fecha).order_by('fecha').values('lec_dia')[0:1])   
        if not c_d:
            return 0
        else:
            if not c_d[0]['lec_dia']:
                return 0
            else:
                return ((c_d[0]['lec_dia'] - self.lec_dia))    
    consumo_d= property(get_cd)

    def get_cp(self):
        c_p = list(ConsumoElect.objects.filter(pgd=self.pgd).filter(fecha__gt=self.fecha).order_by('fecha').values('lec_pico')[0:1])    
        if not c_p:
            return 0
        else:
            if not c_p[0]['lec_pico']:
                return 0
            else:
                return ((c_p[0]['lec_pico'] - self.lec_pico))    
    consumo_p= property(get_cp)
   
    def get_total(self): 
        return (self.consumo_d + self.consumo_m + self.consumo_p)
    consumo_total= property(get_total)

    def get_veitePorciento(self): 
        if self.consumo_p != 0:
            return round(self.consumo_p / self.consumo_total * 100)
        else:
            return 0
    veitePorciento= property(get_veitePorciento)
    
    def get_FP_diario(self): 
        r = list(ConsumoElect.objects.filter(pgd=self.pgd).filter(fecha__gt=self.fecha).order_by('fecha').values('reactivo')[0:1])
        if not r:
            react = 0
        else:
            react = (r[0]['reactivo'] - self.reactivo) 

        if self.consumo_total != 0:
            return round((self.consumo_total) / sqrt((self.consumo_total * self.consumo_total) + (react * react)), 2)
        else:
            return 0
    FP_diario= property(get_FP_diario)

    def get_FP_mensual(self): 
        d = list(ConsumoElect.objects.filter(pgd=self.pgd).filter(fecha__gt=self.fecha).order_by('fecha').values('dato')[0:1])
        if not d:
            dat = 0
        else:
            dat = (d[0]['dato'] - self.dato) 
 
        if self.veitePorciento != 0:
            return round((self.veitePorciento) / sqrt((self.veitePorciento * self.veitePorciento) + (dat * dat)), 2)
        else:
            return 0
    FP_mensual= property(get_FP_mensual)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        fe=date.strftime(self.fecha, "%Y-%m")
        self.fecha_AM = fe
        self.total = self.consumo_d + self.consumo_m + self.consumo_p
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        unique_together=['pgd', 'fecha']
        verbose_name = 'Consumo Electrico'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Consumo Electrico'
        ordering = ['pgd', 'fecha']
        db_table = 'consumoelect'
```

La suma de los consumos (los consumos son las property `consumo_m`, `consumo_p` y `consumo_d`) los guardo en la property `consumo_total`. El problema es que no puedo utilizar la property `consumo_total` en la `views` pues el ORM no ve ese dato, sin embargo guardo en el método `save` el total y en este caso sí se guarda y se puede utilizar en el ORM, pero no muestra el valor correcto en la BD (pues cada vez que inserto un dato nuevo en las property que guardan los consumos, estas se actualizan y no se actualiza el dato en la BD del total), solamente cuando actualizo registro por registro es entonces que se muestra el valor real.

¿Existe alguna forma de que al guardar un nuevo registro los demás registros de la tabla `ConsumoElect` se actualizen en su totalidad?

Utilizo SQLite como Gestor de Base de Datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas despues de indagar bastante logre solucionar el problema, dentro de mi modelo use signal, lo que hago es que cuando inserto un registro nuevo o modifico un registro ya creado entonces se me activa el signal y actualiza toda la tabla (especificamente el campo total donde voy a guardar el valor). El codigo quedo asi:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=ConsumoElect)
def guardar_valores_iniciales(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    try:
        old_instance = ConsumoElect.objects.get(id=instance.id)
        instance._lec_madrugada = old_instance.lec_madrugada
        instance._lec_dia = old_instance.lec_dia
        instance._lec_pico = old_instance.lec_pico
    except ConsumoElect.DoesNotExist:
        pass

@receiver(post_save, sender=ConsumoElect)
def actualizar_total(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created or instance.lec_madrugada != instance._lec_madrugada or instance.lec_dia != instance._lec_dia or instance.lec_pico != instance._lec_pico:
        consumos = ConsumoElect.objects.exclude(id = instance.id)
        for consumo in consumos:
            consumo.total = consumo.consumo_d + consumo.consumo_m + consumo.consumo_p
            consumo.save()

        instance.total = instance.consumo_d + instance.consumo_m + instance.consumo_p
        instance.save()
post_save.connect(actualizar_total, sender = ConsumoElect)
```

Este código va en el mismo model, despues de `class Meta`, entonces en la funcion save ya no tengo que escribir `self.total = self.consumo_d + self.consumo_m + self.consumo_p`

Answer (score 0):

creo que tienes que hacer uso del metodo modified, o sea introducir la linea de código: self.total.modified = True

Answer (score 0):

a mi me funciona este método, tienes que ajustar los demas campos...

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

    if self._state.adding:           # si es nuevo ponemos a 0 el consumo
       self.total = 0

    else:
       self.total = self.consumo_d + self.consumo_m + self.consumo_p

    return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: me podrias explicar mejor a que te refieres con la parte de ´self._state.adding´, es decir que significa, gracias!

Comment: ´self._state.adding´ se activa solo cuando se graba un nuevo registro, aqui puedes poner las condiciones que necesites cuando es registro nuevo.

Si es una actualizacion de registro, se activa el else de ´self._state.adding´